# Embedding Cocoa Touch Framework with Pods Dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, react-native, cocoapods

I need to re-use my swift cocoa touch framework that has React-Native dependencies from another iOS app.

I'm trying to achieve this by embedding the framework into the target (iOS) app (using embedded frameworks option of XCode)

I have two workspaces:

- Ws1 : Builds Fw and App1 (Everything works fine here, App1 uses the Fw)
- Ws2 : Builds App2 (I'm trying to embed Fw here)

I've integrated App2 with React Native (just as the original workspace, by installing the same version of react-native via npm and installing the pods dependencies)

> Question # 1 First of all, is this the right way to go? Is there a more recommended way of distributing dynamic framework with pods dependencies?

When I do this, I get too many compilation errors for React (that I didn't get when compiling the original project).

The errors don't make sense to me at all since they're all pointing at React Native source code files included from the umbrella header under the derived data of the original workspace I developed my framework in (Ws1).

> Question # 2 Which build setting is causing this?  Do you have any recommendations that I should refer to ? I've been searching for a good while but couldn't find an in depth explanation for the XCode build process for Framework targets with pods dependencies.

I'm very very new to all this ios-XCode dev ecosystem and really appreciate if someone could explain to me what's going on.

(I'm using XCode9.1, CocoaPods 1.3.1, Swift 4.0.2, React-Native 0.50.3)

Comment: After much reading through the CLANG manual - using the otool - checking the runpaths and etc - I still don't know the exact reason but I worked this around by adding use_frameworks! option to the podfile, and and thus compiling all pod dependencies as frameworks and linking dynamically.